# Filter an html table bound to a MySQL table by date

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I have an html table that displays maintenance records. There are 3 columns that have dates in the future.

I want to have a button above the table that checks whether any of these 3 dates are within the next 30 days. If so, the row is displayed and other rows that are not of immediate concern are not displayed.

What is the best approach for achieving a filter like this?

Update: I'm trying to do it in a MySQL query.

I have 3 attributes in the SQL table that are date.

Does anyone know how to query whether the dates are within the next 30 days?

Comment: -1 -- shows little effort to come up with his own solution.

Comment: not sure which approach to use, so I'm trying to find out so I can research how to do it.

Comment: "what is the easiest way to do this?" - javascript

Comment: @Rob, you'll get much farther if you'll tell us what you've tried

Comment: Where do these records come from, if they come from a database maybe it would be beneficial to filter things there and load only the records you want.

Comment: Thanks Melsi, I will try this method now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know how to query whether the dates are within the next 30 days?

Use this :

```
WHERE yourdate BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

uses [between](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between), [curdate()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) and [date_add()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

**Update**

to check multiple dates you need to do :

```
WHERE yourdate BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY)
AND yournextdate BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY)
AND anotherdate BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

Comment: Thanks.can you list the attributes like - WHERE date1, date2, date3 BETWEEN CURDATE()... or do I need to do AND statements with the code above 2 more times?

Comment: @Rob you need to duplicate the whole thing ... i will update my example

Comment: Thanks for that, my fields in the database are type - date. Is that ok?

Comment: @Rob yes as `CURDATE()` returns a date

Comment: Feels like it should be working but I'm getting no results at the moment. My query is this - $query = "SELECT * FROM maintenance WHERE nextService BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND CURDATE()  AND nextMOT BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND CURDATE() AND taxRenewal BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND CURDATE()"; See any problems?

Comment: Actually I want results to be displayed if they match any of the AND statements so do I need OR?

Comment: @Rob: Why you don't get a basic understanding of the MySQL functions ManseUK mentioned? Then you will be able to solve this yourself and gain additional knowledge...

Comment: Ok but why would this - SELECT * FROM `maintenance` WHERE nextService BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND CURDATE() not display a row in the maintenance table where nextService is 2012-04-01. I understand that the functions create an interval of 30 days from the current date to check but don't understand why the query above would not display that row when it is in the date DATE_ADD interval

Comment: @Rob - I had the dates the wrong way around ..... try changing them like my updated answer ....

Comment: @Rob sorry about that - the code i had locally was for showing records from the last 30 days !!! hence why i had it that way around ...